# Latex - Why comments environments do not work in macros?

Tags: macros, latex

I'm trying to crate a macro that could display different levels of details in a Resume, the idea being to be able to state a specific theme and to get details only for relevant entries in my resume.

I'm using class "memoir" to use the \newcomment function. I tried moderncv, but I was not really convinced.

Here is what I've come up with so far :

```
\newcomment{Item}
\newcomment{Descr}
\newcomment{Details}

\newcommand{\cvitem}[3]{
    \begin{Item}\textbf{#1}\end{Item}
    \begin{Descr}\hspace{1cm} {#2}\end{Descr}
    \begin{Details}\\ {\small #3}\end{Details}\vspace{2em}
    }

\commentsoff{Item}
\commentsoff{Descr}
\commentsoff{Details}
```

It works as is, but if I state

```
\commentson{Details}
```

Then I get the error :

```
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> cv_master.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better of using conditionals in the traditional sense. That is, use `\if`-like statements that you can toggle on/off:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifItem
\newif\ifDescr
\newif\ifDetails

\newcommand{\cvitem}[3]{%
  \ifItem
    \textbf{#1}
  \fi
  \ifDescr
    \hspace{1cm} #2
  \fi
  \ifDetails
    \\ {\small #3}
  \fi
  \vspace{2em}
}

\Itemtrue
\Descrtrue
\Detailsfalse

\begin{document}

\cvitem{First}{Second}{Third}

\end{document}
```

Why? It's easier and works in all environments/classes.

Comment: Waww super nice ! Thanks @Werner, I was thinking  about diving into the if statements at some point, I'll definitely do!